# How can I include fields in my ldap query result?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using [activedirectory2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory2) library to query my ldap server.

I am using the find method to query my server, it works fine.

However, the return result does not include those fields which I want.

My code as the following:

```
let ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory2');
let config = {
    url: 'ldap://myservername',
    baseDN: 'OU=myOU,O=myOrg',    
}
let ad = new ActiveDirectory(config);

ad.authenticate(user, password, function (err, auth) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('ERROR0: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        return;
    }

    if (auth) {
        console.log('Authenticated!');
        let query = "&(objectClass=*)(CN=Amy*)";
        ad.find(query, (err, results) => {
            if ((err) || (!results)) {
                console.log('ERROR1: ' + err);
                return;
            }
            console.log(results.other[0]);
        });
    }
    else {
        console.log('Authentication failed!');
    }
});
```

It returns:

```
Authenticated!
{
  dn: 'CN=Amy Tomson,OU=myOU,O=myOrg',
  mail: 'amyt@myOU.myOrg',
  sn: 'Amy ,
  cn: 'Amy Tomson'
}
```

If I want the Job Title field includes in the return result what should I do?